# php: number format is not working

Tags: php, decimal

I need to output a `$result` to two places I have tried

```
echo "<td>" .number_format($result,2). "</td>\n";
```

which results in a long string of decimals.  And I have also tried "%u.1" which simply prints  a ".1" literally after every number.

How do I simply output a numeric result to 1 decimal place?

Comment: What is `$result`? https://3v4l.org/HG1ac is as I'd expect it.

Comment: `number_format` should be correct, but it also can depend on what `$result` contains.

Comment: Show the specific use case (what the value of `$result` is, what you expect the output to be, and what the output actually is).  This will help us help you much better!

Answer (score 2):

You may try as :

```
echo "<td>" .number_format((float)$result, 1). "</td>\n";
```

Comment: If $result was a float then number format would not have been needed.

Comment: I don't think it makes a difference as long as `$result` contains a number, so if `$result = '123.4567'` it still works without casting.

Comment: @Andreas why not? [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) expects a float and returns a string. If you want to format a float like `1.2345678` as `1.23` you can use that function...

Comment: But that is not the case here, OP says he wants to format "1" to "1.00".

Comment: [code]<h2>Celsius to Fahrenheit</h2>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Celsius</th>
                <th>Fahrenheit</th>
            </tr>
            <?php for($index = -10; $index <= 40; $index += 5) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $index; ?></td>
                    <?php $result = ($index * 1.8) + 32; ?>
                    <td><?php echo number_format($result, 1); ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>       
        </table>[/code]

This results in a long string of decimals, not a single place.

Comment: ouch... that sure was ugly. My apologies.  How do I put code in a comment block?

Comment: That is why this is called 'comments' not 'code'. If you want to add code do that in your question. Press the edit and add the code and delete these comments. @Dewey